# OpenLayers override class or method in Android 2.3

Tags: openlayers-2, image

I'm implementing my own image loading mechanism for OpenLayers, because lack of functions in Android 2.3 webview. It will get cached images from Android db.

I want to override `OpenLayers.Tile.Image.initImage()`. What options do I have?

I have try Utils for extending TMS layer, but can't extend initImage.

Comment: Which version of Openlayers are you using? http://docs.openlayers.org/library/mobile.html

Comment: I'm using 2.12,

Comment: "Mobile browsing generally demands a different method of map navigation. OpenLayers built in Navigation and TouchNavigation controls attempt to handle this appropriately by default, using whatever events are available in the browser in use.

These controls were added after OpenLayers 2.10."

Comment: I'm trying to implement own OpenLayers.Tile.Image.initImage() method, not touch controls.